# Shows only 3 most recent data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-9

So I want to display the three most recent data from the 'berita' table.
i have created a function in controller, and an error appears **Call to undefined method stdClass::take()**

```
public function index()
    {
        $data = [
            'berita' => $this->BeritaModel->allData()->last()->take(3)->get(),
        ];
        return view('user.v_home_smk', $data);
    }
```

Comment: i think you need to use 'latest()' instead of 'last'

Comment: @AqibJaved previously i have used latest() , but laravel says latest does not exist.

Comment: It's hard to know how the rest of your site is setup, but it doesn't appear (based on what you've provided) that it's using the typical Laravel Database/Eloquent setup. In *theory*, you should be able to use `DB::table('berita')->latest()->take(3)->get();` but without knowing more about your setup, it's just an educated guess. The `latest()` method probably doesn't exist, because your `BeritaModel` isn't extending the Builder/Eloquent classes required.